# android service overlay touch event

Tags: android, service, overlay, touch-event

I'm trying to make a service which displays a button after the user touches anywhere on the screen.

I looked for a lot of similar topics but, I can't succeed for now.

I tried to display a Layout with TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and some flags but I can't get any touchEvent on my service..

At the opposite, I tried with TYPE_TOAST, TYPE_PHONE, TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, but with that, I have the touchEvent on my service working, but not on the current activity..

Do anyone have a solution to get the touchEvent on the service and still perform actions below the overlay ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. What you are describing is called a tapjacking attack, and it has been blocked on Android since about Android 4.0.

Comment: Yes, I understand the risk but I only want to know when the user touch the screen, I dont care about where he just clicked..
Are there any notification to know if the user touch the screen ?

Comment: @nobody710: "Are there any notification to know if the user touch the screen ?" -- only if you consume the touch event, which would prevent other windows from receiving that touch event.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, I'm going to do that on another way